# @bind causes foreach to wait and doesn’t load all the data

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

So my problem is that once I include @bind the for loop doesn’t execute at the beginning only after I pick all. Then it loads all the data I want.
So is there a way to solve it.

The code:
[image]

And what I see at first:
[image]

and after clicking All:
[image]

If I remove the @bind it works but yeh I don’t have a variable now with what the user picket.
I tried using @bind-value @bind-value:event="oninput"
And obviously it didn’t work. So how can I make it work like intended. So that it load and I have access to the data.

To show how everything works I will just show more of the code should have done it sooner.
Also yes I changed the category so it no longer says empty… I probably should read more about it as I don’t really know what tata change does.
(And as mentioned it works now with the event)
So the Whole search bar

```
@inject NavigationManager _navmenager;
@inject IProductService _ProductService;
@inject ICategoryService _CategoryService;
@implements IDisposable 


<div class="input-group-text">
    <HomeButon/> // just a button to go to the top of the page
    <input @bind-value = "SearchText"
           @bind-value:event="oninput"
           type="search"
           list="products"
           @onkeyup="HandleSearh"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Search..."
           @ref="SearchImput"/>
    <datalist id="products">
        @foreach (var item in Sugestions)
       {
           <option>@item</option>
       }
    </datalist>
<select @bind-value= "Category"  @bind-value:event="oninput" @ref="CategoryInput" list="Categories" class="ComboBox">
     <option>All</option>
    @foreach (var Categorie in  _CategoryService.Categories)
       {
           <option>@Categorie.Name</option>
       }
    
</select>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SearchProducts">
            <span class="oi oi-magnifying-glass"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

@code 
{
    private string SearchText = string.Empty;
    private string Category;
    private int ProductsPerPage = 3;
    private List<string> Sugestions = new List<string>();
    protected ElementReference SearchImput;
    protected ElementReference CategoryInput;

    protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender)
        {
            await SearchImput.FocusAsync();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            _CategoryService.CategorysLoaded += StateHasChanged;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _CategoryService.CategorysLoaded -= StateHasChanged;
        }

    public void SearchProducts()
    {
       
        if (SearchText.Length < 2)
            _navmenager.NavigateTo("/");
        else
        _navmenager.NavigateTo($"search/{SearchText}/{Category}/{ProductsPerPage}/1");
    }

    public async Task HandleSearh(KeyboardEventArgs arg)
        {
            if(arg.Key==null || arg.Key.Equals("Enter"))
            {
                SearchProducts();
            }
            else if(SearchText.Length>2)
            {
                Sugestions = await _ProductService.GetProductSercheSugestion(SearchText,Category);
            }
        }
}
```

And now the code to what it calls.

```
namespace BlazorEcomerce.Client.Service
{
    public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _http;

        public CategoryService(HttpClient http)
        {
            _http = http;
        }

        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();

        public event Action CategorysLoaded;

        public async Task GetAllCategories()
        {
            var response =  await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<List<Category>>>("api/categorys/getcategorys");
            if (response != null && response.Value != null)
            {
                Categories = response.Value;
            }
            CategorysLoaded?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Category controller (Well its just a controller and no I’m currently working with models and not DTOs)

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/categorys")]
    public class CategoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;

        public CategoryController(ICategoryService categoryService)
        {
            _categoryService = categoryService;
        }   

        [HttpGet("getcategorys/",Name ="GetAllCategories" )]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<List<Category>>>> GetCategorysAsync()
        {
            var respone = await _categoryService.GetAllCategorysAsync();
            return Ok(respone);
        }
    }
```

And now to what the controller actually calls. If its necessary to include the model just let my know

```
public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
    {
        private readonly DataContext _data;

        public CategoryService(DataContext data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<Category>>> GetAllCategorysAsync()
        {
            var response = await _data.Categorys.ToListAsync();
            return new ServiceResponse<List<Category>>
            {
                Value = response,
            };
        }
    }
```

O then I call that on the index page.
Tried to move it around didn’t work like I place it in the home button or even just app and sure it got called but still didn’t return the data quickly enough.

I used the event to move the data as if I have it on initialize each time I go to the product details I ask the database again and I really don’t want to do it. So it should only be called if the user access the index page

Comment: Instead of using images to show your code, it's best to add it as a code block to your post. Also, I've edited your post to inline the images so they show up without readers having to click the link.

Comment: I’m so sorry, obviously you were right. The moment that element was loaded the Categories were still 0 as the call to the API hast returned yet. 
So I just created an event that will update it once the call is back. Well once the count ov categories changes.

Comment: @michalUrban: You shouldn't need an event. Post the OnInitialize code (as text) if you want more help.

Comment: The `OnInitialize code`  has got nothing to do with the problem. Instead of trying ot lead the OP astray, please try to undesrtand the issue. Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @MichałUrban.  Without more code and info it's not possible to get to the bottom of your problem.  What I can see from the code you have shown and the comments above is you haven't solved your root issue.  Adding an event is Ok to say that the list has been updated, but not for the initial load.  There's a flaw in your load logic that will bite you if you don't sort it!

Comment: @MichałUrban: I totally agree with Henk here.  If you don't call GetAllCategories you don't populate `Categories` which initialises to an empty list!

Answer (score 0):

As this question has generated a lot of "Chatter" amongst some of the main Blazor category answering group, this *answer* sets out a heavily refactored version of the original code in a "Minimal Reproducable Example" format.  If it's wide of the mark, I'll update it.

First some liberties I've taken in the revised code:

1. `category.Id` suggests an Id type field and therefore an `int`, `long` or a `Guid`.  Not normally a string, so I've coded it as a `int`.  Wrong conclusion?
2. I've dropped the interfaces.  You should use interfaces, but they complicate the example code.
3. `Nullable` is enabled.  Rather important in the light of various commentaries.
4. I've made a stab at the data classes, and the functionality in `ProductService`.
5. I've used the Continent/Country context as your Categories/Products.
6. I've replaced lists with `IEnumerable` in properties.
7. I've replaced API calls with generic methods that emulate getting data asynchronously using `Task.Delay`.

First the data classes and services.  I believe in immutablility, hense the records - exactly how you handle `ctor` depends on what version of C# you are using - see the `Required` keyword.

##### Categories

```cs
public record Category
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; } = "No Category Set";
}

public class CategoryService
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<Category>();

    public async Task GetAllCategories()
    {
        // emulate an async call into the API
        await Task.Delay(100);
        this.LoadCategories();
    }

    private void LoadCategories()
    {
        this.Categories = new List<Category>() {
            new Category { Id=1, Name="Oceania" },
            new Category { Id=2, Name="Europe" },
        };
    }
}
```

##### Products

```cs
public record Product
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public int CategoryId { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; } = "No Category Set";
}

public class ProductService
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<Product>();

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetProductSearchSugestions(string search, int categoryId)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return categoryId == 0
            ? Products.Where(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).Select(item => item.Name).AsEnumerable()
            : Products.Where(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) && item.CategoryId == categoryId).Select(item => item.Name).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public ProductService()
        => this.Load();

    private void Load()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>() {
            new Product { Id=1, CategoryId = 1, Name="New Zealand" },
            new Product { Id=2, CategoryId = 1, Name="Australia" },
            new Product { Id=3, CategoryId = 1, Name="Cook Islands" },
            new Product { Id=4, CategoryId = 2, Name="UK" },
            new Product { Id=5, CategoryId = 2, Name="France" },
            new Product { Id=6, CategoryId = 2, Name="Spain" },
            new Product { Id=6, CategoryId = 2, Name="Andorra" },
            new Product { Id=6, CategoryId = 2, Name="Austria" },
        };
    }
}
```

##### Registered Services

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProductService>();
```

##### Demo Page (Test.razor)

And the page.  I've refactored the code and removed stuff that isn't directly related to answering the question.

1. The page gets the Category list in `OnInitializedAsync`.
2. `categoryId` is a classic old style property and includes calling an `event` when it changes.  We need this to update the datalist if it currently contains values.
3. I've separated out the actual value from SearchText (updated by `OnChange` in the bind) from the value used to filter the datalist driven by an event handler on `@ininput`.
4. The logic on the data list filter ignores case and uses `contains`.
5. I've included a debounce throttler which throttles the *type ahead* speed to what the backend can keep up with plus a backoff period.  The code is at the bottom of this answer.  This is initialised in the page `ctor`.

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager _navmenager;
@inject ProductService _ProductService;
@inject CategoryService _CategoryService;

<div class="input-group">

    <input @bind-value="this.searchText"
           type="search"
           list="products"
           @oninput="HandleSearchAsync"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Search..."
           @ref="this.searchInput" />

    <datalist id="products">
        @foreach (var item in this.suggestions)
        {
            <option>@item</option>
        }
    </datalist>

    <select @bind=this.categoryId class="form-select">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        @foreach (var category in _CategoryService.Categories)
        {
            <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
        }
    </select>

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SearchProducts">
            <span class="oi oi-magnifying-glass"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    private InputThrottler<string> inputTextThrottler;
    private string searchText = string.Empty;

    private int _categoryId = 0;
    private int categoryId
    {
        get => _categoryId;
        set
        {
            _categoryId = value;
            InvokeAsync(async () => await this.CategoryChangedAsync());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> suggestions = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    private ElementReference searchInput;

    public Test()
        => inputTextThrottler = InputThrottler<string>.Create(this.GetProducts, 100);

    // this loads the service
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => await _CategoryService.GetAllCategories();

    protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await this.searchInput.FocusAsync();
    }

    private void SearchProducts()
    {
        // what you want to do
    }

    public async Task HandleSearchAsync(ChangeEventArgs e)
        => await inputTextThrottler.QueueRequestAsync(e.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);

    public async Task CategoryChangedAsync()
        => await inputTextThrottler.QueueRequestAsync(searchText);

    private async Task GetProducts(string search)
    {
        this.suggestions = await _ProductService.GetProductSearchSugestions(search, this.categoryId);
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

##### The debounce class:

```
public class InputThrottler<T>
{
    // Debounce task and private properties
    private bool _queued = false;
    private int _backOff = 0;
    private Func<T, Task> _taskToRun;

    private InputThrottler(Func<T, Task> toRun, int backOff)
    {
        _backOff = backOff;
        _taskToRun = toRun;
    }

    public static InputThrottler<T> Create(Func<T, Task> toRun, int backOff)
        => new InputThrottler<T>(toRun, backOff);

    // This method only runs _taskToRun when it isn't already running, plus the backoff
    // If you need to update the UI call StateHasChanged at the end of _taskToRun
    public async Task<bool> QueueRequestAsync(T value)
    {
        // If we're currently running the async task then exit
        if (_queued)
            return false;

        _queued = true;
        // run the task
        await _taskToRun.Invoke(value);
        // apply our backoff period
        await Task.Delay(_backOff);
        _queued = false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

##### Select and Integers

Note that the `select` is mapped directly to the `int`.  No need to switch to a `string`.  The Razor compiler handles this for you with it's `BindConverter`.  Here's the source code the compiler generates:

```cs
__builder.AddAttribute(19, "value", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.BindConverter.FormatValue(this.categoryId));
__builder.AddAttribute(20, "onchange", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(this, __value => this.categoryId = __value, this.categoryId));
```

[image]

Comment: With all due respect, I can see that your code works, but you fail to state what is wrong with the code provided by the user ( except that you've mentioned previously that the OP doesn't call GetAllCategories, and thus the Categories list is never  populated, which is true, in which case you can simply add code to the service to do that. That's not big deal. Where is the issue with his code that is demonstrated in the images provided? Is it related to the fact that he binds the select element to a string while you bind it to an int,

Comment: is it because the `value` attribute of the `All` option is missing ? Is it because he initially binds to an empty string? Sorry, but you don't provide any explanation as to reason or reasons why the OP's code fails.